# Https and SSl issue in Titanium appcelerator IOS mobile Application

Tags: ios, api, ssl, https, titanium-alloy

I have preare a API call using **HTTPClient(titanium ios mobile application)**.

it is a Login page so ihave use **https protocal**,(https"//example.com)

but it returns a following error message,

**"A connection failiure Occured. SSL problem(Possible causes: SSL may include a bad/expired/self-signed certificate,clock set to wrong date"**.

But the same https url has work fine in **Rest Client(Google App)**, so from web site has SSL authority.

i have work to solve this issue over a whole day,

How can i solve this issue?

Note: if i used **validatesSecureCertificate : false** its works. but i want a secure connection. so i want to works even i set this as **validatesSecureCertificate : true**.

Comment: Does the certificate have a valid date? Is it self signed? How many levels down is it from the CA, Apple has limits on the signing chain. Does it with from curl? Running Charles Proxy might help to see the server response.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Zalph, yes I checked, The SSL certification exp. date is valid until 2015, actually SSL certificate has been expired on a week before. but 4 days before certificate has been Renewed.When i tried with "curl" command, it shows "curl:(60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed"., Can you please guide me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.